# Help understanding the field of rational functions with real coefficients (Pugh).

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to parse the following excerpt from Pugh's *Real Mathematical Analysis* (in particular, the parts that I have bolded):

"One example is the field $\mathbb{R}(x)$ of rational functions with real coefficients. Each such function is of the form
$$R(x) = \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$$

where $p$ and $q$ are polynomials with real coefficients and $q$ is not the zero polynomial. (It does not matter that $q(x) = 0$ at a finite number of points.) Addition and multiplication are defined in the usual fashion of high school algebra, and it is easy to see that $\mathbb{R}(x)$ is a field. The order relation on $\mathbb{R}(x)$ is also easy to define. If $R(x) > 0$ for all sufficiently large $x$ then we say that $R$ is positive in $\mathbb{R}(x)$, and if $R − S$ is positive then we write $S<R$. **Since a nonzero rational function vanishes (has value zero) at only finitely many $x ∈ \mathbb{R}$, we get trichotomy: either $R = S, R<S,$ or $S < R$. (To be rigorous, we need to prove that the values of a rational function do not change sign for $x$ large enough.)** The other order properties are equally easy to check, and $\mathbb{R}(x)$ is an ordered field."

Firstly, I'm trying to understand what is meant by "since a nonzero rational function vanishes (has value zero) at only finitely many $x \in R...$" Is this just, essentially, a restatement of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra (i.e., that any non-zero polynomial has a number of roots at most equal to its degree), but extended to rational functions somehow? Furthermore, I don't see how this implies trichotomy (which suggests I'm, indeed, misunderstanding the point he's trying to get across).

Secondly, I don't see why, in order to rigorously prove that the defined relation is an order on $\mathbb{R}(x)$ "we need to prove that the values of a rational function do not change sign for $x$ large enough." I understand (from basic calculus) that, for a rational function $f/g$, as $x$ approaches infinity, we need only to look at the the ratio of the leading coefficients (if $f$ and $g$ are of equal order), etc., but proving that (rigorously) is a different story, and more importantly *why* I need to prove it completely escapes me.

Any help unpacking this a bit would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If a non-zero rational function $R$ vanishes, it implies that $p$ vanishes. By Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, $p$ only vanishes finite number of times. Hence $R$ vanishes only finite number of times.

We define $R$ to be positive if $R(x)>0$ for $x$ that is sufficiently large. We define $R(x)$ to be negative if $R(x) < 0$ for $x$ that is sufficiently large.

Are we able to compare two rational functions using the definition above? That is given $R$ and $S$, can we say whether $R=S$, $R>S$, or $R< S$? To answer that question, we have to check whether $R-S = 0 $, $R-S > 0 $ , or $R- S <0$. Suppose you have proven that $R-S$ remains a rational function, the question is now for each rational function $R$, can we always conclude that $R=0$, $R>0$ or $R<0$ using the definition of $R=0$, $R>0$ or $R<0$. We have to prove that rational function doesn't behave like sine or cosine where it switches signs forever. (well, one might know that a mathematical trick works, but not everyone knows why does it work, a proof helps in clearing this doubt).

Note that a polynomial can only changes sign at its root. Suppose $p \equiv 0$, then  $R= 0$. Suppose not, then $p$ has finitely many roots $p_1< \ldots< p_k$. Also $q$ has finitely many roots $q_1< \ldots < q_m$. Hence polynomial doesn't changes sign after $\max(p_k, q_m)$. Hence either $R > 0$ or $R< 0$.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the order on $\mathbb{R}(x)$ by saying $\frac{f}{g}>0$ if the quotient of the dominant terms of $f$ and $g$ is $>0$. It's not that hard to show that this is an order relation. It turns out that $\frac{f}{g}>0$ in this order if and only if the values of $\frac{f}{g}$ are $>0$ for $x$ large enough. That is something not hard to show. It's based on this fact: the sign of $a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x_{n-1} + \cdot + a_0 = a_n x^n( 1 + \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n x} + \cdot + \frac{a_0}{a_n x^n}) $ is the sign of $a_n$ if $x$ is large enough. The expression inside the brackets is positive. Why say it's not zero when you can say it's $>0$.

Comment: You say that it's not hard to show that the above is an order relation, and yet here I am finding it quite difficult. For example, comparing two elements of the set, e.g., $\frac{f_1}{g_1} < \frac{f_2}{g_2}$, doesn't seem very simple. Sure, showing that any given element is positive or negative is not an issue, but say their leading coefficients are 1, 2, 3, and 4 (for $f_1, g_1, f_2, g_2$, respectively). Then, sure, both elements are positive, but how can one element be "greater than" the other?

Comment: @thisisourconcerndude: oh, you cannot just compare the ratios directly, you have to take the difference and see whether for this the ratio is $>0$ or not. It may go either way.

Comment: Right, so I would want to assume that, for example, $\frac{f_1}{g_1} < \frac{f_2}{g_2}$, and then look at the leading coefficients of $\frac{f_2}{g_2} - \frac{f_1}{g_1} = \frac{f_2 g_1 - f_1 g_2}{g_2 g_1}$ and show that $>$ and $=$ can't also be the case for those two elements?

Comment: @thisisourconcerndude: I see. Well, first look at the difference, no need to assume something beforehand. One fact is true: if one fraction is larger than the other, then for large enough $x$ the value of first at $x$ > the value of the other at $x$. It is not that hard, but maybe Pugh makes it a bit too intricate. For fractions it's not that hard.

Comment: Ok, so, when you say "fractions" do you mean, for example, elements of $\mathbb{Q}$? Because I know what it means when the symbol "<" is between two elements of $\mathbb{Q}.$ If, however, by "fractions" you mean elements of $\mathcal{R}$, I do not know what it means when the symbol "<" is between two elements of $\mathcal{R}$. I know when it means when "<" is between an element of $\mathcal{R}$ and the number $0$, but not two elements of $\mathcal{R}$. Similarly, symbols such as "+," "-," and "=" between two elements of $\mathcal{R}$ are a mystery to me.

Comment: @thisisourconcerndude: aha, so you need to get some familiarity with adding and substracting elements of $\mathcal{R}$. Say $\frac{1}{x-1} + \frac{1}{x+1}$.

Comment: Well, assuming that addition works as it normally does between rational functions, the above sum would be $\frac{2x}{x^2 - 1}.$

Comment: @thisisourconcerndude: right, you can also do the difference and see which one is larger.

Comment: Well, the difference would be $\frac{2}{x^2 -1}$. By "which one is larger" do you mean comparing the sum and the difference (i.e., $\frac{2x}{x^2 -1}$ and $\frac{2}{x^2-1}$), or comparing $\frac{1}{x-1}$ and $\frac{1}{x+1}$?

Comment: @thisisourconcerndude: the latter

Comment: Right, well that depends on $x$. So, is the idea here that elements of $\mathcal{R}$ are just like normal rational functions, and the symbol "<" just refers to comparing normal rational functions? See, because if that's the case, if you were to ask me, in general, is one rational function greater than the other, I'd have to say, "that often depends on the input." If you said, "Well, what about their behavior as $x$ approaches infinity?" That'd be a different story. Am I supposed to just ignore local behavior of functions, or something, and take limits? If so, why can I do that?

Comment: @thisisourconcerndude: Really, you are comparing them at $+\infty$. So yes, it is about limits, the limit of the difference